# How to make ajax in Yii2? my code always return HTML instead of JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a Yii2 project and i want to do an ajax with it. The ajax is success but it always return a HTML result instead of json or text. When i set the dataType to JSON it always error though. Can anyone here show me where i left off?

Here are my javascript codes:

```
var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
$.ajax({
    url: 'getkelurahan',
    cache: false,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html', //when i set it to json, it always error
    data: {kecno: isian, _csrf : csrfToken},

    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },

    error: function (error) {
        alert(error.status);
    }
});
```

And here is my controller action (PHP):

```
public function actionGetkelurahan() {
    return 'tes';
}
```

Comment: do mark the answer as correct if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [asJson()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#asJson()-detail)

```
public function actionGetkelurahan() {
    return $this->asJson('tes');
}
```